# Why does run fail after I compile a GoLang project to Web Assembly?

Tags: go, webassembly

I created a Go(lang) project in Visual Studio Code.  I created a main.go file that I will compile to WebAssembly, and another main.go that I will run as a server (to serve my Web Assembly glue file).

For reference, I'm following the tutorial here: https://golangbot.com/webassembly-using-go/

In a Visual Studio Code terminal, I do the following:

[cd to my wasm source folder with the first main.go]

${env:GOOS} = "js"
${env:GOARCH} = "wasm"

go build -o ../../assets/json.wasm

[cd to my server folder with the other main.go]

go run main.go

[I get the following error]

exec: "C:\Users\...\AppData\Local\Temp\go-build3258126417\b001\exe\main": file does not exist

I was able to run this server prior to the build.  What's going on?

This should have just run.  But now I'm not able to run the server.  I get that strange "file does not exist" error.

Comment: Don't use filenames with `go` commands, and generally avoid `go run` outside of small examples. The `go build` command creates a compiled object, which has absolutely nothing to do with later calling `go run`. Yes, `GOOS` and `GOARCH` affect `go run` just like all other commands the compile go source.

Comment: Would you mind elaborating on why we shouldn't use the "run" command?  Yours is the first mention I've seen of this, so I'm curious to hear the reasoning.

Comment: Also, how do you build a file if you aren't supposed to specify a filename?

Comment: `go run` builds a temporary binary, executes it, then deletes it. You normally want to reuse the binary you built if you have not changed anything. You also would normally not deploy a service with the source code and compile it every time you want to execute it, you deploy the binary.

Comment: The `go` tool works on packages, not files (nowhere in the official documentation will you find examples of using `go run` with filenames). For example, if you want to install the current package, `go install`, and if you want to install the package contained in `./cmd` within your module, `go install ./cmd` -- files are not ever individually handled. This is all covered in the basic tutorials.

Answer (score 0):

I spent a lot of time trying to figure this out and finally got it!  Here's the deal:

Either or both of the GOOS and GOARCH environment variables that are required by the build go command (for webassembly) seem to conflict with the go run command.  I don't know why.  I discovered this in a backwards kind of way.

(TLDR: use different terminals to build and run and don't set these environment variables globally -- set them prior to every build. Use the Terminal>Split Terminal to maintain the build settings between tests! ).

Using the Visual Studio Code Powershell terminal, I set these 2 variables (or so I thought) and then ran the build.  Then I ran the server to try to see the fruits of my labor and got a strange error in the Chrome console (something about expecting one magic word but receiving another).  It turns out this error is fairly generic and after some googling, determined it probably meant something happened with my build.  After trying a few more times unsuccessfully to build, I decided to set the environment variables in windows (as SYSTEM variables) so that I didn't have to keep setting them when I did my build.

I built again (still no build errors), but then when I went to run the server, I got the

exec: "C:\Users...\AppData\Local\Temp\go-build3258126417\b001\exe\main": file does not exist

error.  At this point, I couldn't run any of my Go servers in any project.  Since the only "global" thing I'd done was set those 2 environment variables, I decided to remove them.  I could now run my Go servers.  But I still couldn't execute my builds in the browser.  What's going on??

I figured that since setting the global environment variables had an effect (albeit, a negative effect) whereas I hadn't experienced that issue when manually setting them directly in the terminal prior to each build, then maybe there was something wrong with the way I was setting the variables (I don't use Powershell very often).

After more googling and some experimentation, I discovered the "correct" way to set these variables in the terminal (noted in my original question).  So manually setting them (the right way) prior to the build fixed the build issue (it wasn't building correctly since those variables weren't being set properly).

Now I knew the variable were getting set properly because now I was getting that error when I set them manually prior to the build.  So now what?

I killed the terminal after build, and then started a new terminal, and the run was successful.

So bottom line: the GOOS and GOARCH environment variables should not be set when running a server, so don't start a server in the same terminal that you used to build the web assembly code!

Comment: Your "bottom line" is incorrect, `GOOS` and `GOARCH` have no effect on running a server, they only change the OS and ARCH you are compiling for. In most cases your server should already be compiled before running it.

Comment: That may very well be the case -- I'm clearly no expert on either of these technologies -- but I have found no other reason for why the runs fail.  Whenever I build in one terminal (where the variables have been set) and then run from another terminal, it works.  If I build and then run in the same terminal, it fails.  That's the only change I'm making to the process.  I would love to know what's causing this, but these 2 variables are all I have to work with.  I have not tried to isolate the issue to one variable or the other.

Comment: `go run` fails because `GOOS` and `GOARCH` are set to the wrong values during compilation. If you had already compiled your server, they would have no effect. You may need them set when compiling the server too, it depends on the use case, but you wrote a lot of words which basically all boils down to "don't leave them set to the wrong values".